# Is it possible to use a sim slot in a Samsung phone as a generic PSAM reader?

Tags: java, android, smartcard, sim-card, samsung

There is an NXP JCOP 4 smart card with java applet on it (https://www.cardlogix.com/product/nxp-jcop-4-java-card-3-0-5-classic/), there is also an Android phone with dual sim and Android 13 (Samsung S23 Ultra). Considering the card is properly cut the way it still works and pinout matches the contacts of nano-SIM card slot, is it possible to send APDU commands to it?

I'm aware of UICC option (issuing a Java card which complies to SIM card standards) - but sadly this smart card is provided by third party and we can't modify it.

So, maybe it's possible to reuse the SIM card reader in Samsung as a generic PSAM reader instead?

I've tried OMAPI so far, obviously no luck - openSession returns "Secure element is not present" for the reader with inserted card.

But Samsung has more libraries in their framework, maybe there is other way?

Thanks

Comment: Smart cards require different voltage levels. Modern SIM cards have a reduced voltage and I am not sure what voltage the NXP JCOP 4 card requires and if a modern phone is still able to provide it. This is what I would check first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Robert yeah, this could be an issue, this card surely works at 3V and 5V voltages, not sure about 1.8V, I will get myself a better card reader and give it a check. I don't want to disassemble the phone yet to measure at the pins. Hopefully this isn't the case and it's just a matter of software control though.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage shouldn't be an issue, the JCOP 4 P71 supports voltage classes A, B, extended B, and C (1.62 - 5.5 V). Usually the second SIM slots in phones are for inserting SIM's from multiple carriers when traveling international, I don't think it will function as a Secure Access Module slot. I do know in Android tablets and POS terminals I've worked with that they typically have a slot/s for SIM and a dedicated one for a SAM.

Comment: Indeed, but I wonder if there is a technical possibility to use SIM reader in a non-intended way (as a SAM reader) - or do they have a specific firmware which won't allow this.

Comment: I believe that is a software limitation of the device, technically a SAM or Smart Card follows the ISO 7816 protocol, so communication wise it the reader/writer can communicate, the issue is whether the software of the device will allow you to  SAM/SIM/Smart card slot in the way you want to. Technically, a SAM or SIM slot is the same, it's just about how it is used and how the manufacturer wants you to use it based off of security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of OS. According to my own experience, some Android phones support OMAPI or TelephonyManager which can be used to send APDUs to the card in the SIM slot. Try to check if either OMAPI or TelephonyManager is supported on your OS.